# How to save my pick list value to custom object FeedbackFrom__c?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, commandbutton

I am having 10 pick list fields for my custom object FeedbackFrom__c Each fields having different VF Page(Totally 10 VF Page) at page 11 am having one submit button. if i click it should save all the selected pick list value as well it should show an average based on my Pick list value.

Note:-  Once submitted, pop up to show " You have rated location name good/average/low/excellent"

Final rating will be an average of the ratings given to all the 10 Fields. Consider low = 1, average=2, good=3, excellent=4

How can i achieve this by using Apex and Visual force.?

Comment: Please update your original question instead of posting new ones.

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need to create 10 vf pages, you can achieve this functionality by using one vf page and one class. You need to create your vf page like wizard,where on clicking the Next button it will show next picklist field and 10 picklist values, you can store this in any string or list of string. Now on 11th page, click on submit button and you can save this in your custom object via controller.

Otherwise if you want to create 11 vf pages then you need to use one controller for that.